# SSAS - How to start the SQL Server Analysis Services manually

Tags: ssas

I am new to this SSAS. I have developed a small SSAS cube. When I try to deploy it causes an error:

> Error 14
>   The project could not be deployed to the '.' server because of the following connectivity problems :  A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.

After seeing the above error msg. I try to start the SQL Server Analysis Services manually in services utility in windows but I'm not able to start them.

Please help me how to start the SQL Server Analysis Services manually

Comment: "After seeing the above error msg. I try to start the SQL Server Analysis Services manually in services utility in windows but I'm not able to start them." Why not? Do you get an error message? What account is the SSAS service using for logon?

Comment: while activating the SQL Server Analysis Services manually in services utility , below error it shows "SQL Server Analysis Services on local computer started and then stopped.Some services stop automatically if they have no work to do for example, the performance logs and alerts service "

Comment: Is there any meaningful message in the windows event log?

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the machine, open "SQL Server Configuration Manager", search for "SQL Server Analysis Services", right click and select "start".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps
**1)Check the SSAS service account... does the password expired for that account?
2)Run Service console using "Run as administrator" option.**